# Increasing the screen resolution in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: display, resolution, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 edition on my Acer 5738Z laptop. The screen size of my laptop is about 15'' but the screen resolution in Ubuntu is stuck at 1366x768. I know that my monitor could give better resolution, because previously I was running Win XP and I was able to set higher resolution there. So, my questions here:

1. How do I increase my screen resolution, here?
2. As per the answer given to a related question, I tried to edit the xorg.conf file, but I couldn't find the file in the place `/etc/x11/`. Should I create this file?
3. If I have to install screen drivers separately, where could I find it?

Comment: [xrandr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xrandr/) is a command that lets you change resolution, but unless you fix the issue in your x11 configuration file, you'll have to run this command everytime (xrandr doesn't always let you change to resolutions not already listed in your configuration file, so you may be stuck fixing it regardless).  This isn't a real answer because it doesn't address your x11 issues, but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 2):

use the following guide.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html

Answer (score 0):

What graphic card are you using? If it's a Nvidia, you should install the proprietary drivers which you find under "System" -> "Administration" -> "Hardware Drivers". After a reboot you should be able to set higher resolutions using "nvidia-settings".

PS: Sorry, this isn't a real answer, but I somehow couldn't add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `xrandr` to see if you have desired resolution, if it is supported, simply switch to it, e.g.

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080
```

If it is not supported, you might need to use `xrandr --newmode` to add the resolution, and use `xrandr` to set to your new resolution.